# How to properly define height on a .overlay class on a background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, overlay

This is driving nuts. I have an overlay class (.color-overlay) which works fine on the main slider. But I cant get it to work on the contact section. If I set the class to "position: absolute" it does work on the contact section but then the height and the z-index gets messed up

http://clients.fariadesign.com/effiebourne/#contact-area

Any help would be very appreciated!
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix i tested in developer-tools: Add the following css:

```
section#contact-area{
    position:relative;
}
```

and

```
div.color-overlay{
    position:absolute;
}
```

and

```
#contact-area .container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Note: If you want an element to be *position:absolute* within another element, the container has to be *position:relative*. else it will be absolute to the window.
Same goes if you want to use z-index: you have to set the element to *position:relative/absolute/fixed*

Answer (score 1):

If you add `position: absolute` to `.color-overlay`, just also add `position: relative` to `#contact-area`. Like that the `.color-overlay` will keep contained in `#contact-area`. I don't however see how there are any messed up z-indexes